# Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:text/html

Tags: spring, soap, wsdl

Hello.
I made a client for WSDL by the manual:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html

But when I start up my application, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:90)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:548)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:496)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:451)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:395)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:386)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:376)
    at com.software.prod.core.ws.WebServiceClient.simpleSendAndReceive(WebServiceClient.java:36)
    at com.software.pro.core.common.ServiceRunner.main(ServiceRunner.java:19)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.<init>(MessageImpl.java:275)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl.<init>(Message1_1Impl.java:67)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.createMessage(SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.java:61)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:182)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there a web service running at whatever URL you are trying to call? It seems as that the response you are receiving is probably a html page or a HTTP error (I would guess 404 - File or Directory not found).

What URL are you trying to call? A web service you created or some external web service?

I would recommend trying to call the web service using SoapUI first (to be sure that the web service exists and is working)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I try parse the url: https://dailydeal.de/api/soap/index/wsdl/